# How can I pop up a UITextField for entering data when an image is tapped?

Tags: ios, popup, uitextfield

If I tap an image,can I pop up the `UITextfield` for entering the data?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a UIAlertView as follows:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                message:@"Please enter your text:"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.placeholder = @"Enter some text";

[alert show];
```

Edit: to handle the returned text, implement the delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex > 0) {
        UITextField *textField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSString *text = textField.text; 
        if(text == nil) { 
            return; 
        } else { 
            //do something with text 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: yes it worked.Thanks David.I want to show the entered data on my screen.Can you explain me that too.Please David

Comment: How to show the entered data on my screen.Can you explain me easy method

Comment: I've added the code to my answer above to handle the text when the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: delegate method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIImageView` .. on its selector action you add a textField to your view .. just in that simple your implmentation will be. and don't forget to set `userInterActionEnabled = YES` for the imageView since the default value is NO.

Comment: Can you explain me in more detail please Malek_Jundi